# How to find all the classes that have included a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a module called `Nameable` and some models that include this module.

Is there a way to know which models (classes) have included this module?

Comment: *When* do you want to know? There's always `included` and `extended`.

Comment: hey @DaveNewton I'm setting up a callback on guard that will run all specs whenever I change one module (lets say `Nameable`). So to answer your question, I'd like to know at anytime what are the classes that have the `Nameable` included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've figured out how to find at least the name of all the classes.

```
Module.constants.select { |c| (eval c.to_s).is_a?(Class) && (eval c.to_s).include?(Nameable)}
```

Don't know if it's the best way to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this would be:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map { |model| model.include?(Nameable) }
```

This will give you list of values `true` or `false` depending on whether a model includes `Nameable` module.

You can manipulate the body of `map` to return the data you like (which I could not get from your question).